# COVID-19 Variants

Tags: covid-19, virus, coronavirus

I have been looking at this "new variant" of the virus which causes COVID-19 and the British Medical Journal has said

> **What do we know about this new SARS-CoV-2 variant?**
> It’s been snappily named VUI-202012/01 (the first “Variant Under Investigation” in December 2020) and is defined by a set of 17 changes or mutations. One of the most significant is an N501Y mutation in the spike protein that the virus uses to bind to the human ACE2 receptor ([Wise, 2020](https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.m4857)).

Yet, [The University of Sheffield (2020)](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/news/nr/new-strain-covid-more-infectious-1.892276) pointed out that there was a virulent "new strain" (G614 vs D614) identified sometime before July. Is this the same variant but renamed to VUI-202012/01 or am I confused?

### References

The University of Sheffield (2020). *New, more infectious strain of Covid-19 now dominates global cases of virus* https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/news/nr/new-strain-covid-more-infectious-1.892276

Wise, J. (2020) Covid-19: New coronavirus variant is identified in UK *BMJ 371* :m4857 https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.m4857

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confused. The VUI-202012/01 strain has some 17 mutations, *some* of which have been seen separately before. See [COG UK summary](https://virological.org/t/preliminary-genomic-characterisation-of-an-emergent-sars-cov-2-lineage-in-the-uk-defined-by-a-novel-set-of-spike-mutations/563):

[image]

COG UK suspects that that many mutations have accumulated in a chronic case of infection which served as a "living lab". ECDC give this approximation of the spread of the new kid:

[image]

In contrast [G614](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867420308205) has been dominant for a while by now:

[image]

Note that more "new strains" have been discussed before, aside from G614; see e.g. my snippet from comments in *Science* to [a related question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/25344/10980).

Comment: By the way, the SA paper has been made available https://www.krisp.org.za/manuscripts/MEDRXIV-2020-248640v1-de_Oliveira.pdf and the UK banned travel from SA as a result of those findings. https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-55428953

Comment: In the final image: it seems the size of the arrow (underneath virus) indicates more particles shed by the virus?  What are these particles and what does greater shedding imply?